# Building oauth login with Scribe

Tags: java, facebook, twitter, oauth, scribe

I have read too much pages and tried scribe samples but I miss the most important point - what is unique and persistent user id for oauth authentication?

I want to implement website where user can sign in with Google, FB, twitter etc. I expect that flow is:

1. servlet asks selected authorization provider for request token
2. servlet constructs authorization URL and redirects user there
3. user grants a permission
4. authorization service redirects to callback and passes verifier as parameter
5. callback's servlet asks authorization provider for access token

Now I can use this access token in provider's APIs, for example to browse google drive or post malicious tweets. Fine, but all I want is to get some kind of id that I can store in database and associate it with user account. So when user comes next time, I can recognize him.

I do not think that access token is what I want. I ran scribe examples and this value changes with each call.

Shall I find some provider API that returns user's login and call it each time he logs in? I do not like this idea because this is (in my eyes) extra HTTP connection for each login. And for example google drive sample will return bunch of data, when all I need is few characters. I think that I miss some important point there. Or is it really designed this way?

Comment: http://openid.net/connect/ is interesting concept that does what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens are opaque. They don't contain user information. What everybody does in that case is keeping a separate database with [`USER_ID`, `ACCESS_TOKEN`] so when the user logs in you can fetch it's access token. If you log to multiple services perhaps you also need a `SERVICE_NAME` to separate twitter from google tokens.

### Edit

OAuth is not an authentication or login protocol, it wasn't designed as one so, while you may be able to get the user identity via ad-hoc extensions ([Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/access_token) returns the `user_id` on the access token response) or making further requests, it will always be a hack.

Perhaps a better fit for your needs is [OpenID](http://openid.net/) (and scribe won't help you here, unfortunately)

Comment: How will I map a user from some OAuth service to his account (user_id)? When I ran your samples, I received unique access token per each call. So it seems that I have to perform one additional request witht his access token to find service's user id, am I right?

Comment: Yes but I guess your application has some information of the user that it's requesting authentication

Comment: I saw few websites, where I could register with facebook, twitter, google and so on. They did not know me upfront. And I could use another computer to log in again with selected service. So I expected that they associate created user with some id from OAuth provider. I am unhappy that the protocol lacks this information. It is inefficient to perform addition request and download lots of data just to take one word of it.

Comment: Is there any other way to get permanent user identifier that do not rely on cookies than to perform some authorized request with access token that returns service's user id?

Comment: I don't understand the issue, do you mind rephrasing?

Comment: You said that everybody has table with [USER_ID, ACCESS_TOKEN]. But if I do not receive a cookie in HTTP request, I do not know returning user. He initiates OAuth login which returns me **new** access token. So I still cannot map this user to his existing account, right? So what shall I do now to recognize him? Shall I use provider's API (with access token) that will return me provider's user login?